# How to extract 3000 characters after certain words which appear several times in text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file:

> "Accounting Principles. Negative Pledge Clauses . Clauses Restricting
>   Subsidiary Distributions . Lines of Business......Accounting
>   Principles: is defined in the definition of IFRS. Administrative
>   Agent: SVB......In the event that any Accounting Principles (as
>   defined below) shall occur and such change results......"

In this file, "Accounting Principles" appear three times and "IFRS" appears one time.

I try to extract 3000 characters (or 300 words) after each "Accounting Principles" and "IFRS". Now I only can extract the characters after the first occurrence of "Accounting Principles", and write separate codes for "Accounting Principles" and "IFRS". So my question is how to extract 3000 characters after each occurrence of "Accounting Principles", and how to write one code that I can deal with "Accounting Principles" and "IFRS" together, rather than using two separate codes?

Many Thanks!

My code is as followed:

```
import os
sourcepath=os.listdir('try/')
for filename in sourcepath:
    inputfile='try/'+filename
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        text=f.read()
        index=text.index('Accounting Principles')
        right=text[index: index+3000]
        print(right)

import os
sourcepath=os.listdir('try/')
for filename in sourcepath:
    inputfile='try/'+filename
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        text=f.read()
        index=text.index('IFRS')
        right=text[index: index+3000]
        print(right)
```

Comment: Sorry for typos, In this file "Accounting Principles" appear three times

Answer (score 1):

This program finds every instance of either "Accounting Principles" or "IFRS" and prints the matched string along with 30 characters beyond its end.

```
import re

with open('x.in') as fp:
    text = fp.read()

for m in re.finditer("Accounting Principles|IFRS", text):
    print(text[m.start():m.end()+30])
```

Comment: It works well, Thanks! Could I ask a follow-up question please? I have many files, and for each file I extract those characters. I would like to print the those characters +filename into one text file called"outfile.txt". My code doesn't work:print(text[m.start():m.end()+30],filename, file=open('outfile.txt', 'a'))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` to create a marker wherever `"Accounting Principles"` or `"IFRS"` and then iterate over the full_string

```
marked_data = re.sub('Accounting\sPrinciples|IFRS', '*', open('filename.txt').read())
new_data = [marked_data[i:i+3000] for i in range(len(marked_data)-3000)]
```